# What is the fastest known algorithm for finding eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, computational-mathematics

What is the fastest known algorithm for finding eigenvalues?
Second and third fast are also of interest if they are simpler, basically anything better than the standard solve characteristic polynomial plug into equation

Comment: "better than" what? And  what is the size of the matrices? Also all eigenvalues or just some?

Comment: There is no universal answer. Different algorithms are suitable for different features of $A$ and for extracting different information. If $A$ is symmetric, you should use that; if you know whether the eigenvalues of $A$ have any real or imaginary part, you should use that; if $A$ is sparse, you should use that; if you only need some eigenvalues (usually either the large or small ones), you should do that. And then when $A$ is badly conditioned, there are *all sorts* of ways to precondition it, and their efficacy is very much specific to the problem at hand.

Comment: That said, LAPACK's general purpose routine is based on QR iteration, which (when used with shifting and upper Hessenberg reduction) is frequently good for nonsymmetric problems which are not so large that you cannot assemble the matrix $A$.

Comment: can you provide a link to an article that explains it to someone who is not knowledgable of these things?